# tensorflow-windows installation with CPU support only through python3.5

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to install Tensorflow in windows7 with CPU support only.
The installation was successful using a native pip, as instructed in tensorflow site. But i am not able to validate the installation. It is generating an error message instead of printing Hello, Tensorflow.
error showing- *tf is not defined*,.
*sees is not defined*.
the screenshot of the error: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFLvr.png

Comment: What are you doing to validate the installation? is "import tensorflow as tf" throwing an error?

Comment: i am using the code below which is shown in the tensor flow site....import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace / output of the error message?

Comment: C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>import tensorflow as t
f
'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>
C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>
C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>
C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>

Comment: C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>hello = tf.constant('H
ello, TensorFlow!')
'hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>sess = tf.Session()
'sess' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\satyajeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>

Comment: the above error msgs are showing

Comment: You have to import TF in a PYTHON console. Write first 'python' in your windows console, and then 'import tensorflow as tf'

Comment: i hv tried that. then too its showing error

Comment: You should copy the python error in your main post. Have you installed python and added it to your path? is the command 'python' actually working?

Comment: ya python is working fine..and the python path is also added.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot in your question? thanks.

Comment: have added the link of the screenshot..pls check it..@Sergiodiaz53

Answer (score 0):

Working

```
py -m 3.6 pip install tensorflow
```

The lack of AVX instruction in CPU can cause this error.

Try this [wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.6.0/py36/CPU/sse2) for [python3.6](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/python-3.6.7-amd64.exe)