# Error importing tensorflow on python 3.6 and 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started a course online that required tensorflow installation. After successfully installing it, whenever i try to import i always get error

I initially installed it on py3.7 then i installed it on 3.6, still nothing changed still getting the same error

```
>>>import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\LEKAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I expect tensorflow to import without any problem

Comment: Follow this https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html, Let you know if you got

Comment: [tensorflow-windows installation with CPU support only through python3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50902042)

Comment: both aren't working

Comment: Common reason for this error being thrown is not having vs C++ redistributables dowloaded.Make sure all the [required softwares](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) are installed.Windows 7 or later (64-bit)
[Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)